# Am I tagging these questions correctly?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm not doing this just to get extra eyeballs on my questions, but I'm concerned that I might be throwing people a curveball with my tags.  Is the `mschart` tag referring to an older technology (like VB6 time frame)?

[How to do aligned scrolling through two chart areas without using AlignToChartArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957157/how-to-do-aligned-scrolling-through-two-chart-areas-without-using-aligntochartare)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904427/how-do-i-get-the-data-in-a-point-charttype-and-a-rangebar-charttype-to-line-up-ex

[Align x axis of one ChartArea with y axis of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862624/align-x-axis-of-one-chartarea-with-y-axis-of-another)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) versus [.net-3.5](/questions/tagged/.net-3.5), I'd only use the latter if it's a feature that is specific to 3.5.  These days the tag is mostly useless since .NET 4.0 is out and it brought over just about everything from 3.5 so very few things are 3.5 specific.

Everything else is generally okay.  When you're uncertain whether or not a tag is appropriate, the tag wiki description is greatly helpful.  Unfortunately in your case, the tag wikis for each of those tags is generally undefined except for the most popular ones like [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).  You could take the opportunity to help the community further by checking out the questions in that tag and making sure your impression of what that tag represents accurately reflects that activity within the tag and then authoring the tag wiki (and tag wiki summary) yourself!

Also, if nobody has retagged your posts within a few hours or so, generally that means you did an okay enough job :)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the tag wiki.  Didn't even look at those the first time around.